# PHP - CURL HTTPS Request - NFSe Curitiba

Tags: php, libcurl, nfe, php-5

Estou realizando uma integração com WebService para envio de RPS, para emissão de NFS-e, estou utilizando a linguagem de programação PHP, e a biblioteca CURL. Nesta integração é obrigatório ao fazer qualquer requisição o envio do certificado digital, este já temos e estamos enviando no parâmetro ***(CURLOPT_SSLKEY)*** o caminho absoluto do certificado.

**Os parâmetros da CURL estão da seguinte maneira:**

```
    $_options = array (
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://pilotoisscuritiba.curitiba.pr.gov.br/nfse_ws/NfseWs.asmx?WSDL',
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 60,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 60,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
        CURLOPT_SSLKEY  => /var/cert/cert.pem, // certificado
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $_content,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $_header
    );
```

**Tenho o seguinte retorno :**

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<EnviarLoteRpsResposta xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <NumeroLote xsi:nil="true"/>
 <DataRecebimento xsi:nil="true"/>
 <ListaMensagemRetorno>
  <MensagemRetorno>
   <Codigo>E504</Codigo>
   <Mensagem>O certificado digital do prestador de serviços é obrigatório.</Mensagem>
   <Correcao>Envie junto a requisição do serviço o certificado digital do prestador de serviços.</Correcao>
  </MensagemRetorno>
 </ListaMensagemRetorno>
</EnviarLoteRpsResposta>
```

**Alguém já passou por isso antes e/ou tem alguma ideia de como solucionar este problema ?**

Comment: Deve passar como string `'/var/cert/cert.pem'` primeiramente. Agora, pode ser que além do `SSLKEY` (que a chave privada)  seja preciso que especifique a chave pública (usando o `SSLCERT`). E obvio, é preciso que defina a senha da chave privada (`KEYPASSWD`), se houver alguma. Além de tudo, quando você desliga o `VERIFYPEER` ele deixa de usar/verificar o `CAINFO`, criando problemas de segurança, mas não vem ao caso.

Comment: Estou enviando assim agora : 
$_options = array (
            CURLOPT_URL => $this->_wsdl,
            CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 60,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 60,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
            CURLOPT_SSLCERT => $this->publicKey, // Chave publica
            CURLOPT_SSLKEY  => $this->privateKey, // Chave privada
            CURLOPT_KEYPASSWD => '*******',
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $_content,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $_header
        );

Comment: E agora está me retornando uma página html : 

  <div id="content">
   <div class="content-container">
    <fieldset>
     <h2>403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.</h2>
     <h3>You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.</h3>
    </fieldset>
   </div>
  </div>

Comment: Sabe o que pode ser agora ?

Answer (score -1):

Bom dia, boa tarde ou boa noite depende do horário que tiver lendo.

Eu tive o mesmo problema recentemente quando entrei em contato com o pessoal do Iss Curitiba foi descoberto que o problema estava no certificado.

Então meu cliente teve que fazer um novo com o padrão ICP Brasil.

No meu caso isso resolveu.